# Как правильно вставить переменную?

Tags: php, переменные

```
echo '<TD>'.$_SESSION['x'].'</TD>';
```

После **x** нужно вставить переменную `$i`.
Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo '<TD>'.$_SESSION['x'.$i].'</TD>';
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать на будущее

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<TD>'.$_SESSION[$i].'</TD>';
```

В следующий раз пробуйте просто по-разному ставить.

Comment: Вы х забыли

Comment: Да, прошу прощения. Прочитал не внимательно.
echo '<TD>'.$_SESSION['x'.$i].'</TD>';

Оказывается выше уже ответили. Ну ничего. Повторение...как говорится)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<TD>'.$_SESSION['x'.$i].'</TD>';
```

Конечно же так, Вы чего? Это же легко! Но тут, наверно, Вам не надо  ставить `'<td>'`.